# Azure media player(AMP) not working on chrome if script file is saved locally

Tags: azure-media-services

I have saved the source of sample AMP video http://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/samples/dynamic_setsource.html locally and trying to play video. It works in IE and Edge but not in chrome. if i host this file it works.
Can you please help me understand what is wrong here?
You can try running script in IE an Chrome to see the difference.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Skill Cloud</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="http://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/1.7.1/skins/amp-default/azuremediaplayer.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/1.7.1/azuremediaplayer.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Skill Cloud</h1>
    <video id="azuremediaplayer" class="azuremediaplayer amp-default-skin amp-big-play-centered" tabindex="0"> </video>
    <script>
        var myOptions = {
            autoplay: true,
            controls: true,
            width: "100%",
            height: "auto",
            poster: ""
        };
        var myPlayer = amp("azuremediaplayer", myOptions);
        myPlayer.src([{ src: "http://amssamples.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/91492735-c523-432b-ba01-faba6c2206a2/AzureMediaServicesPromo.ism/manifest", type: "application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml" }, ]);
    </script>
    <footer>
        <br />
        <p>© Microsoft Corporation 2016</p>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: http://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/samples/dynamic_setsource.html can play on chrome.

Answer (score 1):

When you run the code locally, Chrome opens your index.html with the file:// protocol. Due to Chrome's security policy local resources aren't allowed to be loaded and that's what's preventing playback. (If you check out your JavaScript console, I bet you'll see a similar error.)

To workaround this, you can use an IDE like Visual Studio or WebMatrix that will automatically set up a local web server for you so you can access your page with http://localhost:8000 or whichever port you prefer.

If you don't want to use VS or WebMatrix, you could also use Python's Simple HTTP server. Hope this helps and happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to run locally then you can just replace http with https without downloading it locally.

For example:

```
 <link href="https://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/1.7.1/skins/amp-default/azuremediaplayer.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="https://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/1.7.1/azuremediaplayer.min.js"></script>
```

Also need to replace

```
myPlayer.src([{ src: "https://amssamples.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/91492735-c523-432b-ba01-faba6c2206a2/AzureMediaServicesPromo.ism/manifest", type: "application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml" }, ]);
```

This works for me atleast, Happy coding!