# My Azure Media Services Videos won't play in Azure Media Player

Tags: html, azure, video-streaming, media-player, azure-media-services

I'm being asked to add a video player to my company's web app that plays streaming video from Azure Media Services.

Using both the Azure portal and the Azure API I have been able to load and publish the video files we want to present.

I found samples [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-azure-media-player/) and [here](http://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/docs/) showing how simple it is to set up the Azure Media Player in your HTML page.

I added the relevant bits to our web app and the player shows up, but nothing plays. In Chrome, the player is blank. In IE11, the player shows "Invalid Source". In Edge, the player shows "This type of video file isn't supported.".

I plugged the URL's of our videos in the [Azure Media Player Demo](http://ampdemo.azureedge.net/azuremediaplayer.html) and they worked fine.

I created stripped down HTML files with just the basics for the video player using Azure's samples and their own promo video.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Azure Media Player Test</title>
        <link href="//amp.azure.net/libs/amp/1.3.0/skins/amp-default/azuremediaplayer.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src= "//amp.azure.net/libs/amp/1.3.0/azuremediaplayer.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        This sample came from <a href="https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-azure-media-player/">https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-azure-media-player/</a>
        <br />
        <br />
        <video id="azuremediaplayer" class="azuremediaplayer amp-default-skin amp-big-play-centered" controls autoplay width="640" height="400" poster="" data-setup='{"nativeControlsForTouch": false}' tabindex="0">
            <source src="http://amssamples.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/91492735-c523-432b-ba01-faba6c2206a2/AzureMediaServicesPromo.ism/manifest" type="application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml" />
            <p class="amp-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that supports HTML5 video</p>
        </video>
    </body>
</html>
```

and

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Azure Media Player Test</title>
        <link href="//amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/skins/amp-default/azuremediaplayer.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="//amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/azuremediaplayer.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        This sample came from <a href="http://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/docs/">http://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/docs/</a>
        <br />
        <br />
        <video id="vid1" class="azuremediaplayer amp-default-skin" autoplay controls width="640" height="400" poster="poster.jpg" data-setup='{"nativeControlsForTouch": false}'>
            <source src="http://amssamples.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/91492735-c523-432b-ba01-faba6c2206a2/AzureMediaServicesPromo.ism/manifest" type="application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml" />
            <p class="amp-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that supports HTML5 video</p>
        </video>
    </body>
</html>
```

I get the same results with these as I did in our web app, i.e. blank or "Invalid Source" or "This type of video file isn't supported."

I assume I'm missing something basic, but what?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a web server to host the code you wrote or just running it locally? If you're running it locally, playback won't work in chrome or edge without some form of a webserver. See this answer for more details: 
[Azure media player(AMP) not working on chrome if script file is saved locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37410256/azure-media-playeramp-not-working-on-chrome-if-script-file-is-saved-locally/37892541#37892541)